# remain processes after exit application on some devices

Tags: android, c++, process, android-ndk, kernel

My application has come c++ code and many pthreads. I close application with `exit(0);`. After that, I listed running process with `adb shell ps`. This command shows me current running processes on device.

Output shows there are still some processes related my application (their names are my applicaiton name). After running application several times, these garbage processes number increases. At some point, device cannot response, because of there is small memory left.

I realized some issues. When application starts, it has a pid and I can see that on process list (with `adb shell ps`). Also, I see some processes that theirs parent process is application processes. And, if I exit from application, application process is removed from list but previous child processes still remaining. And, their parent processes become 1 (I think it is main OS process or something like that).

This problems occurs on HTC One. it doesnt occur on Samsung Note 2. After close app, all child processes are killed automaticly on Samsung.

How can I prevent this child processes remaining?

Comment: Well, kill them yourself before `exit`ing. You know which processes you launched and their PIDs, right?

Comment: yes I know main application PID, but I dont know child processes PIDs.

Comment: What are those processes? How do you launch them? If you need to track your child PIDs you could use good ol' `fork/exec` so the parent knows its children's PIDs, and SIGCHLD to notify the parent when a child dies before him.

Comment: I dont have any idea. OS divides them. I cannot find where they are created. On Samsung, there doesnt become child processes, only one main processes.

Comment: If you're not launching child processes yourself, what you're seeing *might* be an artefact of the `pthread` implementation. Do you have any thread still alive when you `exit`? If so, `join` them first (you might need to add a way to notify the threads that they must stop).

Comment: Yes, I have many pthreads. I think like you said. I m trying it.

Comment: `exit()` should call Linux `exit_group()` which kills all the threads in the process.  The problem appears to be the child processes of the exiting process; their parent is dead, so they get reparented to initd (pid 1).  Killing the processes explicitly (with say `kill(0, 9)` to wipe the process group) doesn't work if the parent crashes before it kills them; you really want the child processes to die when the parent dies.

Comment: Now, I solved the problem like this. First, I find child processes first (from java), then when Application close, I killed child processes first, then exit the application. it seems related with CPU type and OS version. higher version like 4.2.x has this problem. but I am still not sure why child processes is created and why they arent killed when I kill main process

Answer (score 0):

I want to know why you have not use fork just use pthread,it can make a new process??(my linux program is not good)

mybe you can try the code before application exit

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("killall " + applicationName);
```